# How to evaluate the following convergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do you evaluate this series?:

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{\pi^{2n + 1}}$$

Using the ratio convergence test, I figured out that the infinite sum converges. I am just stuck on evaluating it. I have tried writing out couple terms of the sum, but could not get an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Can you compute the sum of the series $\;\displaystyle\sum_{k\ge0}(2n+2)x^{2n+1}\,$?

*Some details:*

$$\sum_{n\ge0}(2n+2)x^{2n+1}=\Bigl(\sum_{n\ge0}x^{2n}\Bigr)'=\Bigl(\frac1{1-x^2}\Bigr)'=\frac{2x}{(1-x^2)^2}.$$

Comment: Does that evaluate to $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$? I saw that it is the derivative of $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}x^{2n +2}$

Comment: Not exactly. Note this is a series with odd terms.

Comment: No. It's a rational function.

Comment: Sorry I am really not getting it.

Comment: You were almost burning! It's $\;\dfrac1{1-x^2}$.

Comment: But how can I relate that to the original question?

Comment: Set $x=\dfrac1\pi$.

Comment: To compute the sum above, did you use the geometric series formula?

Comment: Why, yes, naturally!

Comment: Isn't the derivative of the sum above equal to $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}x^{2n +2}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38555/discussion-between-bernard-and-mat).

Answer (score 0):

By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|<1$ we have:
$$ \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+k}{k} z^n $$
so by taking $k=1$ it follows that:
$$ \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = \sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1) z^n $$
and by taking $z=\frac{1}{\pi^2}$ it follows that:
$$ \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{\pi^2}\right)^2} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(n+1)}{\pi^{2n}}$$
so:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(n+1)}{\pi^{2n+1}} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^3}{(\pi^2-1)^2}}.$$

Comment: We did not learn such a theorem, so I do not think I can use it.

Comment: @Mat: then read the linked Wikipedia page and learn it. Once you know how to prove something, you may use it any time you like. It won't be anyone shooting at one for using something true.